# How do I find the remainder of $23! +29!$ divided by $13! +19!$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, divisibility

> What is the remainder of $23! +29!$ divided by $13! +19!$?

**Attempt**

$$23!+29!=23![1+(29×28×27×26×25×24)]$$ and

$$13!+19!=13![1+(19×18×17×16×15×14)]$$

Now how do I proceed..I am stuck at this initial stage.

Please help.

Comment: A little comment, that $(23!+29!)$ is divisible by  $13!$.  But I have no idea of how to proceed too

Comment: But I'm sure I don't help even a bit since that horrifying $1+14\times 15\times \dots \times 19$ is terrible... Do you have any nice method to proceed?

Comment: Not actually..I'm struggling with this part..but i can see that all of the denominator part(except 1) is +10 of the numerator part..Can it help in some way?

Comment: Feels bad after this: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=factorize+1%2B14*15*16*17*18*19 (copy the whole link, it does not work)

Comment: @ElfHog $79\times247279$.  Worked for me.

Comment: Nice, but the $247279$ seems to be extremely difficult to mod out.  If computer can be used, big mod algorithm may help.

Comment: But the problem is said to be solved strictly by hand! :(

Comment: The answer is $35027147675520000$. Even if we factor out the obvious 13!, that's still $5625025 = 5^2\cdot7\cdot32143$. Just how is that going to be solved by hand?

Answer (score 1):

**Partial answer**

$$\begin{align}\frac{23!+29!}{13!+19!}&=\frac{23!(1+24\cdot25\cdot26\cdot27\cdot28\cdot29)}{13!(1+14\cdot15\cdot16\cdot17\cdot18\cdot19)}\\&=\frac{23!}{13!}\cdot\frac{2\cdot3\cdot7\cdot2+(2\cdot24)\cdot(3\cdot25)\cdot(7\cdot26)\cdot(2\cdot27)\cdot28\cdot29}{13\cdot5\cdot3\cdot3+(13\cdot14)\cdot(5\cdot15)\cdot(3\cdot16)\cdot17\cdot(3\cdot18)\cdot19}\cdot\frac{13\cdot5\cdot3\cdot3}{2\cdot3\cdot7\cdot2}\\&=\frac{23!}{13!}\cdot\frac{195}{28}\cdot\frac{84+48\cdot75\cdot182\cdot54}{585+48\cdot75\cdot182\cdot54}\cdot\frac{812}{323}\\&=(23\cdot22\cdot21\cdot20\cdot19\cdot18\cdot17\cdot16\cdot15\cdot14)\cdot\frac{3\cdot5\cdot13\cdot29}{17\cdot19}\cdot\frac{84+48\cdot75\cdot182\cdot54}{585+48\cdot75\cdot182\cdot54}\\&=(3\cdot5\cdot13\cdot14\cdot15\cdot16\cdot18\cdot20\cdot21\cdot22\cdot23\cdot29)\left(1-\frac{501+48\cdot75\cdot182\cdot54}{585+48\cdot75\cdot182\cdot54}\right)\\&=(3\cdot5\cdot13\cdot14\cdot15\cdot16\cdot18\cdot20\cdot21\cdot22\cdot23\cdot29)\\&\quad\quad-(14\cdot15\cdot16\cdot18\cdot20\cdot21\cdot22\cdot23\cdot29)\cdot\color{red}{\frac{167+3\cdot75\cdot182\cdot54}{1+16\cdot25\cdot14\cdot18}}\end{align}$$

and I think the next step would be to find what happens to the fractional term.

**Using a calculator**

The fraction becomes $$\frac{2211467}{108001}\approx 20.476...$$ and unfortunately $108001$ is prime...

Comment: Why your answer is a partial answer ?

Answer (score 0):

Well... as a simple check, we have the common factor of $13!$ which I will ignore initially, then

$$ \begin{align}
14\cdot 15\cdot 16\cdot 17\cdot 18\cdot 19 + 1 &= 19535041 \\ 
(23!/13!) \equiv 19535040\cdot 20 \cdot 21 \cdot 22 \cdot 23 &\equiv 19322521 \bmod 19535041 \\
(29!/13!) \equiv 19322521\cdot 24 \cdot 25 \cdot 26 \cdot 27 \cdot 28 \cdot 29 &\equiv 5837545
 \bmod 19535041  \\
19322521 + 5837545  &\equiv 5625025 \bmod 19535041
\end{align}$$

so $23! + 29! \equiv 13!\cdot 5625025 \bmod (13!+19!)$

Comment: How can this be done by hand? (see OP's comment)

Comment: Slowly and carefully :-)